# Help identifying attachment part for a rider mower/tractor (picture)

Tags: part-identification, lawnmower, tractor

I have had a renter at my home who left some items behind in my shed. One of them is the item shown which I **believe** is a rear attachment for a rider mower/tractor. It does not fit mine (a craftsman). Can anyone help identify what this is?  I'd like to give it away rather than chuck it into the trash, of possible.

I've tried google image search with no luck, and I can't find any part number on the item either stamped into the metal or on a sticker.  I'm assuming I have the item in the upright orientation in the pictures.

[image: Unidentified attachment]

[image: Unidentified attachment2]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for a Cub Cadet riding lawn mower. I'm not sure *which mower* it's for, but you can find the part [listed here on Cub Cadet's website](https://www.cubcadet.com/en_US/miscellaneous-classification/support-bracket/783-0601-0637.html). Here's an image of the bagger support bracket:

[image]

Which is the part standing up in your images. The hooks (facing to the left in your bottom image) are usually used for an easy on/off of the back of the mower. I dug around on their site for quite some time and couldn't find the other part, but would assume it is for a bagger support or the like. You might be able to send the images to Cub Cadet Product Support department and get more information. I'm sure they could tell you exactly what it's for and which machine it goes on.

Comment: A little google image search with cub cadet keywords has helped get closer to solving my mystery.  Nice.  I think the bottom plate (that is sitting on the ground) is possibly on backwards?  It's this: https://www.picclickimg.com/d/l400/pict/402753329022_/Cub-Cadet-LT1042-Model-190-670-100-Twin-Bagger-Support.jpg which suggests that it's for an LT1042 and is some kind of twin bagger support.

Comment: @highbandwidth - I think the bottom plate is an extension so you can continue to attach/pull things like a small trailer while having the bag mount stay on the tractor.

Comment: @paulster, probably ... looks like this is part of a a twin bagger support 190-670-100 https://www.partswarehouse.com/Cub-Cadet-190-670-100-Twin-Rear-Bagger-Kit-s/380618.htm.   That bracket is on backwards, and it's #26 in the exploded diagram.  Thank you Internet Hive Mind, you did it!